# Is this usage possible?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to use "wing" as a verb meaning "blowing something in a certain direction," as in the following?

"The wind winged a thick heap of clouds off westward, to cloud over the corn field that had been, but a short time earlier, dyed gold with the gloaming."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wing#Verb), in this this sense, is defined as a verb meaning 'throw'. So yes it is possible to use it here.

> "The wind threw a thick heap of clouds off westward..."

Although unrelated, the alliteration of "wind" and "winged" can be seen as a great literary device.

In summary, the sentence is both grammatically correct, uses alliteration and features "winged" as a verb meaning "threw".

Answer (score 1):

Such use of *[winged](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/winged#Verb)* is possible, but *[wafted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wafted)* would be better.

The sense  “To throw” of verb *[wing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wing#Verb)* is less well-known and less commonly used than all but one of its other senses, which are (from wiktionary)

> 1. (transitive) To injure slightly (as with a gunshot), especially in the arm.
> 2. (intransitive) To fly.
> 3. (transitive, of a building) To add a wing (extra part) to.
> 4. (transitive) To act or speak extemporaneously; to improvise; to wing it.
> 5. (transitive) To throw

On the other hand, all but one of the senses of *[waft](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waft#English)* have proper semantics for use in the question's example:

> 1. (ergative) To (cause to) float easily or gently through the air.
> 2. (intransitive) To be moved, or to pass, on a buoyant medium; to float.
> 3. To give notice to by waving something; to wave the hand to; to beckon.

Answer (score -1):

It's completely normal to use winged as a verb.

> I winged my way back home.

It's completely normal to use winging as a verb.

> I'm winging it your way.

It's completely normal, but uncommon, to use wing as a verb.

> Wing it to me dude.

Regarding the last one, you can use **any word** as a verb in English.  It's kind of weird that way.

---

Regarding the particular sentence you posed,

> "The wind winged a thick heap of clouds off westward, to cloud over
>   the corn field that had been, but a short time earlier, dyed gold with
>   the gloaming."

Yes, it's completely fine.  You **would not normally** use "winged" that way.

English is confusing like that:  that use of "winged" would either sound:

*1) extremely sophisticated .. like something Hemingway would write*

or

*2) it would sound like one is a "non-native-speaker" and you did not quite know how to use the word.*

Does that make sense? English is kind of weird like that.  I hope that makes sense.

I have already supplied a more normal-sounding, more commonplace use of "winged" as an example.

Note that very simply..

> "The wind threw a thick heap of clouds off westward...

sounds very good indeed, and is perfectly correct.

Comment: Obviously you are a new member and don't show any effort on your part to try to answer my question. This is a waste of my time and I shall let this be the end of this squabble.

Comment: I am not squabbling, but you should click to insert a normal nickname.  On these sites generally/often people ignore questions by "no name" users as they are often "hit and run" users.  I'm not sure how much more info I can give you about your question!!

Comment: @Joe Hi there, I would like to point out that you've done so many things against the rules here. Patent copying of answers, impersonation of mods, a outright rudeness. Be careful what you say to others please, thank you.